# How to create an installer for WCF service that's hosted via Console application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, installation, console-application

I have a wcf service and I have a console application that hosts the service
The console application also holds a SQL-CE database, if it makes any difference.
I'm using .net 4 and IIS 7.5?

I prefer doing it with Visual studio 2010 setup project.

Comment: Hey - Why do you mention your IIS version if you want to host the service in a console app; in that case you should use a `ServiceHostFactory` or `WebServiceHostFactory` to run the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's hosted in a console application, it means you have to start the console application to start the service.
To start the console you need a user logged in. To make it log in automatically, you can use [Autologon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905).

To create an installer just create a setup project as you would in any windows application.

Comment: Thanks, autologon is a great idea.